# How to end ping test after a timeout when the Wi-Fi is not reachable?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to test my connection in an Android (Kotlin) application with the InetAddress API but the **timeout** delay doesn't seem to work when my Wi-Fi connection is labeled by Android as "Connected, no Internet".

My function is as follow :

```
suspend fun getPingNetwork(callback: (isOk: Boolean, description: String) -> Unit) {
        println("enter getPingNetwork")
        try {
            val isReachable =
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    InetAddress.getByName("my-server.example")
                        .isReachable(1000)
                }
            if (isReachable) {
                callback(true, "Ping reached server.")
            } else {
                callback(false, "Ping did not reach server.")
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            callback(false, "Ping exception.")
        }
    }
```

The ping will execute correctly with a good connection, but if it's "Connected, no Internet", the timeout will last for more than 10 seconds, which is way too much.